# Setting up exisiting drupal site locally, and not seeing any admin privileges

Tags: drupal, admin, local

I have a project where I am taking an existing, live, drupal 7 website that I pulled off a server, exported a db file, and trying to set it up locally with MAMP.

I have the website running, and everything seems to be running smoothly, but, I am unable to access the admin section.

My question is, where in the drupal config/files do I edit to make myself the owner of the website, giving me access to the administration section?

The only thing I could think of was changing a setting in my settings.php file.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Drupal user with uid 1 has full access, as first step, I would suggest to get yourself user 1 credentials to your Drupal installation.

https://www.drupal.org/node/186256

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to log in using the same credentials as the live site at [your-local-address]/user. If you don't know what those credentials are, you can always look up user 1 in the `users` table, which will give you the username of that user. Next, you can reset their password using one of the options on this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/992400

Once you do, you'll have everything you need to log in as user 1 which will give you full access to the admin section.